# Amazon Cognito - Query For Multiple User Ids

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Is there a way to query Amazon Cognito for multiple User Ids at once? If yes, are there any limitations?

Comment: Hello Raj! Yes you can do this using the [`ListUsers`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ListUsers.html) API call. Are you looking for how to construct the API request, example code for use with a specific SDK and if so which language, or the CLI command? And in terms of limitations, are you looking for quotas?

Comment: Can I pass multiple UserIds (usernames) to ListUsers to search for in a single API request?

Comment: What are you exactly looking to do? Filter based on user IDs?

Comment: Yes. But I want to filter based on multiple UserIDs at once. Possible?

Comment: Working with AWS SDK for Node.js. Thanks a ton!

Comment: I could not find anything online which lets me search multiple UserIds at once. So would be great if you could post an answer. Thanks.